# Is it possible to chain transactions from an orbitary account in a single block

Tags: mempool

In most blockchains, it's possible to chain several outgoing transactions for an account. In Tezos we've tried to do the same, but got errors like:

```
Netezos.Rpc.InternalErrorException: [{"kind":"temporary","id":"proto.008-PtEdo2Zk.contract.counter_in_the_future","contract":"tz1Ywh6HfQoXnjeoN1GduTydLY73oj9DAgFw","expected":"958117","found":"958118"}]
```

It looks like the node is not able to chain several transactions depends on each other in the mempool.

Do we do something wrong or it's normal behaviour of the node? What are the best practices to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to send multiple transactions from a single account is grouping them into a single operation. Note that only manager operations (`transaction`, `delegation`, `origination`, `reveal`) can be grouped into a batch.

Here is an example (see more in [Netezos docs](https://netezos.dev/docs/get-started.html#forge-an-operation)):

```
var counter = await rpc.Blocks.Head
    .Context.Contracts[address].Counter.GetAsync<int>();

var opGroup = new ManagerOperationContent[]
{
    new TransactionContent // tx 1
    {
        Source = address,
        Counter = ++counter,
        ...
    },
    new TransactionContent // tx 2
    {
        Source = address,
        Counter = ++counter,
        ...
    },
    ...                    // etc
};

var bytes = await new LocalForge().ForgeOperationGroupAsync(branch, opGroup);
...
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, this is clear. But in this case, I have to monitor if the previous batch included in the block or not. It would be awesome to have transactions chaining functionality in the node mempool as other blockchain nodes have.

Comment: @KonstantinRyazantsev you can do it actually. Here is an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WOTxoX

Comment: thank you. Your example works well and we've figured out why we have an error - before actually build a transaction we do the estimation via dry-run. And dry-run fails with an error if there is a transaction in the mempool

Comment: if there is a tx in the mempool and the next one is passed with `counter+1` then the node responds with the `counter_in_the_future`. If there is a tx in the mempool and the next one is passed with `counter` then the node responds with `Counter 958124 already used for contract`

Comment: There is an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YDL633

Comment: I see. I think it's just a specific of `/run_operation` method. Feel free to open an issue on https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos

Comment: Done https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/1405. Thank you @Groxan!